# Q: MariaDB INSERT is causing other inserts to take place in other tables

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, mariadb

Below is the INSERT I am doing in phpMyAdmin and not only does it add a new product but it is taking the new ID it creates and adding it twice to another table called products_categories with a sub-category entry (the same sub-category each time, 26) and in random ID locations, not at the end of the table (e.g. ID 42605 instead of the end of the table at 63896). I have looked at Triggers in phpMyAdmin and there is nothing there. Is there somewhere else I can look?

`` INSERT INTO products set `sku` = '99999' ``

Comment: It's got to be a trigger. Perhaps you do not have the access rights to see the triggers or just looked at the wrong place. You better ask somebody familiar with your database for explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately, this is my database on a dedicated server. I have root access and I have run 'show triggers;' and there is nothing. I have never been so confused here, ha.

Comment: So I believe I fixed the issue by dumping the tables that were having fields automatically added to them, creating a new tables from that data, moving the original tables with issues to a new name, and renaming the new tables to the old name. Issues have stopped but for the life of me I can't figure out why. I wish there was something I do do to search the database of other possible tables that were being updated!